# Количество нажатий клавиши мыши при применении редактора на основе AbstractCellEditor

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Подскажите пожалуйста, для таблицы JTable создан редактор на основе AbstractCellEditor. Каким образом задать количество нажатий клавиши мыши для перехода к редактированию ячейки аналогичное DefaultCellEditor().setClickCountToStart(2)? В приведенном коде 0 и 2 столбец при первом нажатии клавиши получает фокус, при двойном переходит в режим редактирования, 1 же сразу переходит в режим редактирования. Необходимо сделать поведение аналогичное другим столбцам.

```
public class PP extends JFrame {
    private String data[][]=new String[][]{{"","",""},{"","",""}};
    private String column[]=new String[]{"Фамилия","Имя","Отчество"};
    public PP() throws HeadlessException {
        super("Кадровая работа");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
        JTable jTable=new JTable(data,column);
        jTable.setRowHeight(40);
        jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new EditorJTA());
        this.add(new JScrollPane(jTable));
    }

    private class EditorJTA extends AbstractCellEditor
            implements TableCellEditor {
        private JTextArea editor = new JTextArea();

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(editor::requestFocus);
            editor.setLineWrap(true);
            editor.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            editor.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                    {
                        stopCellEditing();
                    }
                }
            });

            editor.setBorder(new LineBorder(null, 0));
            return editor;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return editor.getText();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PP();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В EditorJTA можно переопределить метод isCellEditable

```
  @Override
  public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
      if (e instanceof MouseEvent) {
        return ((MouseEvent)e).getClickCount() >= 2;
      }
      return true;
  }
```